# GoLang - Reading large text file in chunks

Tags: go

Below is the code for file read, split and word occurence:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "strings"
)

type text []string

func (wordList text) wordCount() map[string]int {

    keyCounts := make(map[string]int)

    for _, word := range wordList {
        _, ok := keyCounts[word]
        if ok {
            keyCounts[word] += 1
        } else {
            keyCounts[word] = 1
        }
    }
    return keyCounts
}

func main() {
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("shakespeare.txt")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
    //fmt.Println(b)
    str := string(b)

    var words text = strings.Fields(str)
    //fmt.Println(text)

    var d [25]string
    n := copy(d[:], words[:25])
    fmt.Println("Number of elements copied: ", n)
    for i := 0; i < len(d); i++ {
        d[i] = "'" + d[i] + "'"
    }
    fmt.Println(d)
    fmt.Println(len(words))
    fmt.Println(words.wordCount()["MIDSUMMER-NIGHT'S"])
}
```

---

and `file.txt` has below content:

```
日本語 读者 你好吗
A MIDSUMMER-NIGHT'S DREAM

Now , fair Hippolyta , our nuptial hour 
Draws on apace : four happy days bring in 
Another moon ; but O ! methinks how slow 
This old moon wanes ; she lingers my desires ,
Like to a step dame , or a dowager 
Long withering out a young man's revenue .
```

---

1) Can `file.txt` be read in chunks? because `file.txt` size is in GB

2) Can you suggest text processing package to perform word count?

Comment: You can use bufio.Scanner for both.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Can we mention the chunk size to read from file using `bufio.Scanner`?

Comment: Use bufio.Scanner with the [ScanWords](https://godoc.org/bufio#ScanWords) [split function](https://godoc.org/bufio#Scanner.Split) to scan words from a file.  Scanner reads data in chunks from the underlying reeader. The [Scanner (words)](https://godoc.org/bufio#example-Scanner--Words) example is a good starting point for the code.

Comment: @overexchange: what do you mean by "mention the chunk size"? Are you encountering a problem with reading up to the size allowed?

Comment: @overexchange use Scanner.Buffer to set buffer size.